# get string from visual selection

Tags: vimscript, visual-mode

Having some text selected in visual mode, I need some way of turning it into a string that can be used in an expression.

I have tried this

```
function! VisualSelection()
    normal! `<""y`>
    return @"
endfunction
```

and it works by itself, but when I want to use it in a mapping vim complains because of the `normal` command, which, guess what, can't be used in mappings with `<expr>`, so I need some different way of doing this.

I've found out that it is possible to find mark positions with regex like `\%'<` and `\%'>` but I don't know how to find regex in the file in an expression (`match` wants a string, and I haven't found any similar function that searches in the file itself)

Comment: pd: stack exchange markup is weird; kinda like markdown yet not really. I miss my \```<language> ... \``` for multiline code :'(

Comment: Just FYI, fenced code blocks aren't part of Markdown; they were added by later variants. (I think first by MultiMarkdown?) [StackExchange's markdown dialect](https://vi.stackexchange.com/editing-help) is pretty close to the original.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533565/how-to-get-visually-selected-text-in-vimscript on SO.

Two solutions, plus many variations, have been provided and discussed.

- One based on manual decoding on text in between `getpos()` results,
- and the traditional one based on `normal! gv"ay`, with restoration of register and so on.

  ```
  function! lh#visual#selection() abort
    try
      let a_save = @a
      silent! normal! gv"ay
      return @a
    finally
      let @a = a_save
    endtry
  endfunction
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that link, I tried one of the solutions and it works. As for the second solution you mention, that one doesn't work (sadly) because vim doesn't like it and throws an error (E523), as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Should probably use `getreg`/`getregtype` in this case, if writing a plugin

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer, Sorry, I didn't think your code will work, and it does. As such I dismissed the `<expr>` part of your question. My mistake.

Comment: @Mass, the thing is the code as been working for quite sometime now, long before `getreg()` and all. So far I haven't been in a use case where I need more precision. I'll need to investigate further.